# File.Exists using the wrong root path?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my c# class I wrote I have a photo property that returns the photo source if the image exists (nothing or default image otherwise). In my code I use:

```
    public string Photo
    {
        get
        {
            string source = "~/images/recipes/" + id + ".jpg";

            if (File.Exists(source))
                return "~/images/recipes/" + id + ".jpg";
            else
                return "";
        }
    }
```

If I get the FileInfo() information for this image I see that I tries to find this image in the following directory: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\images\recipes*

Of course the image is not located in that directory and File.Exists is returning me the wrong value. But how can I fix this?

Comment: The question was retagged (I guess?) to ASP.NET but you need to specify if this is indeed ASP or you're trying to get the Unix '~/' convention to work on Windows.

Comment: The original question title referenced ASP.NET and the context makes it seem like the question is about using '~/' as the Application root, not the Unix convention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(source)))
```

Comment: I have no access to the Server object inside this class.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` will work the same as `Server.MapPath`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map the relative path back to a physical path:

```
string source = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/recipes/" + id + ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use:

```
Server.MapPath(source)
```

As you can not be 100% sure where the code will be running from, ie. it will be different in development and on a production server. Also are you sure ~/ works in windows? Wont that just be interpreted as a directory named ~? Unless thats what you want.

Comment: Server.MapPath should interpret '~' as 'ApplicationRoot'.  Otherwise, yes it is treated as a directory name.